# What is the function of c:\BOOT

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, bcd, bcdedit

There is a folder c:\boot on hard disk.

It contains files like: BOOTSTAT.DAT and BCD

What is that?

I got that when I install windows.

Basically I am looking for files and directory where windows decide which partition is C: and which partition is D:

I want to ensure that directory never changes.

Comment: You found it.  See my answer below:

Answer (score 1):

That's data for the Windows bootloader; it's what gives you a recovery console.

Comment: what is recovery console?

Comment: If Windows ever has problems booting it lets you restore your computer to a previous configuration so that it can boot again. What exact options and data it has depends on your model of computer and what vendor configured it.

Answer (score 0):

It is the Boot Controller/Manager configuration directory.

See below how to get into it if you have a multi-boot system.

But first, you will want to have a `Repair` boot disk on hand so you can get into the Recovery Console.

You can create one in the `Backup and Restore` utility.  It gives you all the tools you need to fix the master boot record and other startup problems.

Here is an article about that:

[How to Create a System Image Backup in Windows 7, 8, or 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/4241/how-to-create-a-system-image-in-windows-7/)

This article shows both how to make a full system image backup, but more importantly it shows how to make the repair disk.

Once you have the repair disk you will be ready.

If needed, boot that disk to get to this screen:

[image]

Then follow the instructions in this article:

[HOW TO USE A SYSTEM REPAIR DISC TO RESTORE WINDOWS 7](http://www.dummies.com/computers/operating-systems/windows-7/how-to-use-a-system-repair-disc-to-restore-windows-7/)

---

**BCD is especially interesting when you have a multi-boot system.**

You can get into it using the windows `bcdedit` command, or download the third-party GUI front end for it here:

[Visual BCD - Boot Repair Tool](https://www.boyans.net/DownloadVisualBCD.html)