# Dual boot setup unsucessful with upgraded Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, multi-boot

I had Windows 7 and I upgraded it to Windows 10. I don't know why there was a hidden partition called "windows7 loader" (100 MB) still after upgrade. I ignored it as everything was working fine.

I created a small partition (10 GB) for installing Ubuntu. I had set dual boot successfully sometimes ago with Windows 7. So I cared specially not to format or select C: during installation. However, still it is unsuccessful I can still see Windows 10 files & folders in Ubuntu. **In the page where we are meant to select Windows I can choose Windows 7 loader, but selecting that equals to restart**. Can anyone help me fix it?

I don't care if I lose Ubuntu, but first I want to have Windows 10 and if the process deletes Ubuntu, I don't care, but remember to describe how to do it correctly later.

Comment: Get the community version of EasyBCD and re-add the ubuntu loader to the MBR. I think that should do it.

Comment: Well I can boot into ubuntu sucessfully

Comment: Take a look at this answer that talks about dual booting:  https://superuser.com/questions/896060/what-is-the-function-of-c-boot