# Windows dual-booted device don't start anymore

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot

My Windows 10 side of my dual boot don't work anymore.
When I try to launch it it stays on :

[image]

Usually it didn't stayed at this stage and led me to the login page.

If I press any touch it just shutdown. When I start again on the Windows side it leads me to the "Preparing automatic repair" page :

[image: Preparing automatic repair]

But after the diagnosis it reaches a page telling me Automatic Repair can't do anything.

[image]

I can then go to advanced option and choose either to power off the laptop or troubleshoot it :

[image]

I can then go to advanced option or reset the pc but I don't know what to do :

[image]

I use an Inspiron 15 3000 series.

Comment: Take a look at the answer to this question, regarding how to control dual-booting:  https://superuser.com/questions/896060/what-is-the-function-of-c-boot

Comment: Honestly, this looks like more of a hardware issue, then a software issue (corrupt Windows installation) due to the graphical glitch that happens.

Comment: looks like some problem with windows installation, nothing to do with dual boot or grub or something else. did you tried to login with safe mode? could be faulty hardware driver installation

Comment: @Joey Yes, I just tried and it gives me the first picture with the graphical glitches

Comment: @SDsolar Thank you for your link ! Unfortunately, I can't access the Backup and restore utility as far as I only have access to the steps in the pictures above

Comment: Ah.  That second set of screen-shots is new and shows that you do have the recovery console for your installation, and proves it is not hardware.  Also, the BCD configuration programs I mentioned in my comment require Windows to be running.  Good luck with this one.

Comment: @Marine1 I think either you need to install windows again or find a technician that can troubleshoot your system. You said you tried to initiate windows repair but didn't work right? did you tried to restore to previous version? reset pc? startup repair?

Comment: @SDsolar From the screenshots I have above, do you know if I can save any of my files on an external hard disk ?

Comment: @Joey I tried to restore to previous version and tried to reset the PC and it didn't work. The technician told me to reinstall windows. That mean that I will have to do the partition again ... Do you know how can I save the files of both operating systems before doing that? Unless you have a better idea

Comment: You can always save your files.  Your problem appears to only be with the boot sequence.  The best way is to clone the entire drive.  Boot to a Linux LiveCD and use the `dd` command.  Set up your computer so you have a second drive available that is at least as large as your original, then use `fdisk -l` to verify which drive is which.  Presuming your original drive is /dev/sda and the second drive is /dev/sdb and the CD is /dev/sdc, the proper command would be `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb`  -  It will make an exact copy, overwriting everything on the second drive, of course.

Comment: Without doing above, just boot your system using linux OS live version. then you can manually select and copy your files into either separate drive or some other partition. After that you can re-install windows into the same partition now you currently have windows installed in. no need to erase whole drive and re create partitions. in windows setup, just choose current windows partition and then format only that partition. Then install windows into it..                                     I may be able to do something if I could get hands on with the system,since I cant, this'd be better

Comment: Plus,  if you're familiar with linux, there's a way to modify bootloader partition or just get another bootloader from working windows system and use it as the bootloader, I think GRUB 2 gives that facility, but Im not recommending that

Comment: @Joey Okay, I just received a new hard drive, I won't use `dd` as far as I read [here](https://www.google.fr/search?q=what+is+bootloader+partition&oq=what+is+bootloader+partition&gs_l=psy-ab.3...5245.6971.0.7074.8.8.0.0.0.0.94.629.8.8.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.5.404...0i7i30i19k1j0i19k1j0i7i5i30i19k1j0i8i7i30i19k1j0i13i30i19k1j0i8i7i30k1j0i8i30k1.0.lQo6SPsYHoE) that it might even copy the free space of my Windows partition. Yet, I am not able to manually access the Windows partition from my live usb key ... It tells me "This location could not be display" when I click on the icon of this parti

Comment: I'm not clear what's the error message is, but you can try this, install windows into your new drive, create necessary partitions before that. you've no problem accessing other partition data in old drive, right? so for the windows partition in old drive, you can either use disk cloning tool, then copy old windows partition into new drive's partition and inside a folder, so then you can access your data.Or you can try install windows into new drive, plug in old drive and try to access with booted from new disk,in windows OS. so it may let you access windows to windows(NTFS to NTFS).let me know

Comment: @Joey Dear professor Drake Ramorey, I tried using Clonezilla to clone the windows partition but I encounter some issues listed [in the following link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399188/why-cant-i-choose-a-new-hdd-for-directory-browser-for-image-repository) on Unix and Linux stackexchange ...

Comment: @Marine1 I gave an answer there. try it and tell me if you need something. hope it helps